# What is the difference between [mac] and [apple]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should there be a difference? My proposal

- `[mac]` relates to hardware
- `[osx]` relates to the software
- `[apple]` relates to the company specifically.

Comment: and is the site specifically for mac hardware or does it include other apple hardware (iphone, ipad, time capsule, etc) as well?

Comment: I would assume any hardware.

Answer (score 15):

I think that if we have an [apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) tag, it will be used in a way that doesn't add any value. Maybe we can use [apple-inc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-inc) for questions related to the company, and ban the use of [apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple).

Comment: +1 … everything in Ask Different is, or should be, Apple-related.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with KeithB, [apple] is very vague to what it actually refers to in any given situation. [apple inc] is kinda strange, but still better. [mac] is related to hardware questions about all macs. We should of course have [macmini], [imac], etc. for different models. [osx] is regarding the operating system and it's built in functionality, excluding standalone applications like AddressBook, Safari, iCal etc.

As a side note, how about [snow-leopard], [tiger] etc? Is it better or worse than [osx 10.6], [osx 10.5]. And is it possible to alias tags? Like the aforementioned [tiger] <-> [osx 10.4].

Comment: You can alias tags (tag synonyms) but no one has over 2000 reputation to do this yet. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/

Comment: @Chealion: No rep, and not in the top 20 or 100 upvotes.

Comment: I still prefer `[apple]` for the company. `[snow-leopard]` => `[10.6]` are good, though `[10.6]` should be synonymous with SL.

Comment: I see [tag:imac] and [tag:mac-mini] but there are so many different types of each model, I don't find value in that level of detail.

Answer (score 5):

I think that yes, they should be a difference.

The moto of the site says *"Beta Q&A site for power users of Apple hardware and software"*.

As they will have questions on iPad, Mac or the company itself, we should make a difference on these tags.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely, I agree Macintosh *is* just a brand of hardware made by Apple. That's the way of reality.

What's wrong with using the real-world identifiers? How about: [apple] is the name of the company, [macintosh] or [mac] is the name of the computer line, [ios] is software that runs on the i-devices such as iPhones, iPods and iPads, [macos] or [osx] is the software that runs on the Macintoshes.

This is how it is in the real world and not very complicated at all. You can use multiple tags anyway.

Comment: apple is too confusing as covers everything on this site and the tag will not be used just for company related questions - anyway this is a very old question look at the tag wikis for how they are used now which is as per @GlennNilsson's answer