# On the right name of Apple products and softwares

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

May this is too early and maybe I'm the only one concern, but at a certain point shouldn't we correct the name of Apple products and softwares to match their real name ?

For examples :

- **iTunes** instead of Itunes
- **iPhone** instead of Iphone
- **Mac OS X** instead of Mac OSX
- and so on …

Comment: Mac instead of MAC. OS(space)X instead of OSX. ;-)

Comment: [Tag related "right naming."](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tag-corrections)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Particularly in the case of tags, it seems important to get this right for cases like "OS X", where it affects the accuracy of searches.

Answer (score 3):

Correcting in posts would be fine, though no one has edit powers yet so that's a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be allowed to mis-spell certain words to make a point? (I'm not talking about tags, were you absolutely need one authoritative spelling.) Should I be able to write about *iDontWork* when I'm complaining about *iWork*? What about *Micro$oft*?

We have a similar (but more narrow) discussion on the WordPress site, where (for the moment) one user (sometimes) prefers to write *Wordpress* instead of *WordPress*. Since this is the subject of our site, opinions are divided on [whether we should allow this](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/should-we-ask-for-reasonable-consistency-in-style-for-things-like-wordpress-vs), or [provide a way to signal the "protest"](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/proposal-why-wordpress-or-wordpress-and-not-wordpress-campaign/138#138) so others won't edit it away.

Comment: Tags like `[idontwork]` or `[micro$oft]` will be fixed by editing - they don't help people find the question and Micro$oft is rather petty.

Comment: @Chealion: Maybe I was not clear enough, but I was talking about post content, not tags. And indeed these things are petty, but edit wars are generally not about the important things...

Comment: Sorry, I get it now. I'd say no - it detracts from the question. On Super User I've edited questions that had these and never had an issue. There are other ways of making a point without annoying anyone who might actually answer your question.

Comment: Same opinion as Chealion, we shouldn't allow these terms.

Answer (score 0):

### Related

[What is the difference between [mac] and [apple]?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/8546) (2010-08-17)

### Related (but not listed as such in the sidebar)

[Is it OSX or OS X?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/609/8546) (2011-07-28)