# Is it OSX or OS X?

Tags: discussion, osx, site-promotion

Or does it even matter?

As I [mentioned yesterday](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/who-is-this-character-with-the-and-the-running-around-editing-all-these-post), I'm editing a ton of question titles. I tend to change OSX to OS X just out of personal preference, but I wonder if that will annoy anyone?

Comment: Oh it matters ;-) this crowd is picky, detail-oriented, and very vocal

Comment: @bmike thus the barrage of teeny jargon-related questions! CHAOS has a strict no-toe-stomping policy.

Comment: You are off to a great start - getting consensus, asking - but taking action nonetheless :-) This joint is starting to look "real classy".

Comment: Detail-oriented? Moi? Probably avidly so, and it's the attention to detail (amongst other things) that makes this joint all the classier :-)

Comment: Wait, why is this on the meta? Shouldn't this be on the main site?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is now a historical curiosity since macOS replaces OS X. And we have a new data point with the iPhone X in writing being verbalized as iPhone 10 when spoken.

---

Apple's Mac OS X Lion website, documentation, and marketing material all have spaces between OS and X. I'd assume OS X is the correct way to spell OS X. Sidebar, Mac OS X is pronounced Mac Oh Ess Ten, not Oh Ess Ex. This can be confirmed by using the say command in the terminal:

```
$ say OS X             # Returns Oh Ess Ten
$ say OSX              # Returns Oh Ess Ex
$ say X                # Returns Ex
$ say Roman numeral X  # Returns Ex
```

Also, as noted by michaelmichael the proper spelling would be **Mac** OS X.

Comment: That's what I thought. We just like to be careful - sometimes people get snippy when we bust in and rearrange all the furniture! (To wit: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/who-is-lauren-and-why-is-she-changing-posts-introducing-myself)

Comment: Is there any footage of Jobs saying "Oh Ess Ten"?

Comment: Almost certainly. If not [tag:steve-jobs], I have certainly heard other Apple people speak the word "ten" (**never** heard Apple say "X").

Comment: http://www.apple.com/quicktime/qtv/earningsq311/ at 13:33 on the timeline, "First: when we deliver Mac OS X Lion …" (pronounced *ten*).

Comment: As well as the website, I like to refer to the various versions of the Apple Style Guide, e.g. https://help.apple.com/asg/mac/2013/ASG_2013.pdf.  (They revise it every few years, and I haven't checked recently.)

Comment: Great answer, but at some point since Lion, Apple adopted the terminology OS X.  And now (2016) we have macOS Sierra.  In writing specifically about Lion (for exampe) I still like to include the version number and write "OS X 10.7 Lion", at least at the first appearance in the piece.

Answer (score 12):

Now it is neither! As of June 13, 2016, the name has been changed to macOS https://www.apple.com/macos/sierra/

[image]

> During the keynote at WWDC on June 13, 2016, Apple announced that OS X would be renamed macOS to stylistically match Apple's other operating systems, such as iOS, watchOS, and tvOS.

Comment: @JeremyDouglass uh... definitely didn't just edit and change that just now because I didn't notice lol.

Comment: Upvote for the real-time error correction feature on this answer. Which may be needed if Apple keeps changing the <strike>Mac OS X</strike> <strike>OS X</strike> macOS branding....

Answer (score 6):

To be *really* nitpicky, it's **Mac** OS X. They're fanatical about this in Apple Store retail training.

Comment: Is that something I should be striving for when I'm editing? Or is it "colloquially" ok to just leave it at OS X?

Comment: You know what? I stand corrected. Even though http://www.apple.com/osx 404s, all the branding on http://www.apple.com/macosx talks about OS X Lion - no "Mac". Perhaps they've changed their stance since I heard the above anecdote. I'm sure it won't matter much unless Mac OS is still in version 10 by the time iOS reaches its 10th version.

Comment: Yeah, they changed their stance with Lion for some reason and are using "OS X" on the website and marketing material. Though for some reason they still use "Mac OS X" in the actual software. Bizzare...

Comment: It's always been Mac OS X for a long time, but the people that "read the tea leaves" and watch each slide of every keynote that apple publishes have noticed Apple to start to write OS X when it used to _always_ have Mac before the OS. Long time observers feel some references to OS X may stand alone when referring to commonality between iOS and Mac OS X. Best to use Mac until the stand alone usage gains traction or it's clearly meant to be inclusive of iOS and Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks michaelmichael, I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

## Suggestions

I should:

1. always discourage **OSX** (with or without a *Mac* prefix)
2. encourage **Mac OS X** whilst Apple support and licensing for OS X is limited to Mac hardware — currently in [Apple — Legal](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/) there is no OS X without Mac; System Information in the first release of Lion describes Mac OS X …; and so on
3. without wishing to speculate, consider the possibility that Apple may one day license **OS X** for use on hardware that is not Mac — not to be confused with past and present [OSx86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86) (Hackintosh) approaches.

### Related (but not listed as such in the sidebar)

[What is the difference between [mac] and [apple]?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/8546) (2010-08-17) — AFAICT focused on tagging

[On the right name of Apple products and softwares](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/45/8546) (2010-08-18)